# How to use the proper cross product?

Tags: c, vector, algebra, cross-product

So a cross product is v1 = <x1, y1, z1> and v2 = <x2, y2, z2> defined as v1*v2 = <y1*z2 - z1*y2, z1*x2 - x1*z2, x1*y2 - y1*x2> any a output of 32.000000. But I don't know if my code is wrong or wrong it the wrong way. But I'm not getting an weird text. Can anyone help me find the problem in the code?

```
void cross_product( float x1, float y1, float z1,
        float x2, float y2, float z2,
        float* result_x, float* result_y, float* result_z){
        float d = ((y1*z2)-(z1*y2), (z1*x2)-(x1*z2), (x1*y2) - (y1*x2));
        printf("v1 (dot) v2 = %f", d);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7UWu.png)

Comment: Please do not post code and text output as an image - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question. Also, please ensure the posted code is a complete [mre]. That is, include the test code with input values as well.

Comment: This is similar to a previous (now deleted) question. The same comment applies: You can't just blindly copy the formula from the task description. `,` in a maths equation is not the same as `,` in C code. In the code you need to store each component of the cross products into the `result_` output variables. That is, you need 3 seperate variables. In C the comma operator will evaluate to the last expression only (`(x1*y2) - (y1*x2)`) which is clearly not what you need.

Comment: Could you show an example of the result_ ?

Comment: Your `printf` statement suggests that you have reused some code for a dot product rather than a cross product. The result of a cross product cannot be stored in a single variable `d` as you have attempted to do.

Answer (score 3):

As said by kaylum, you need to store the result for each vector in one of your variables `return_` called by reference.

If you want to calculate de distance between your two points in `float d`, you have to make the square root of the sum of the powers of two of the distance between each coordinate.

At the end, your code should look like this:

```
void cross_product( float x1, float y1, float z1,
                    float x2, float y2, float z2,
                    float* result_x, float* result_y, float* result_z)
{
    *result_x = (y1 * z2) - (z1 * y2);
    *result_y = (z1 * x2) - (x1 * z2);
    *result_z = (x1 * y2) - (y1 * x2);

    float d = sqrtf(powf(x2 - x1, 2) + powf(y2 - y1, 2) + powf(z2 - z1, 2));

    printf("v1 (dot) v2 = %f", d);
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  Aside: Recommend using `"%g"` to print _floating point_ than  `"%f"`.  More informative when values are small and less clutter when values are large.

Answer (score 2):

The comma operator evaluates each sub-expression and the final result is the last sub-expression. So in your case it means `d` only ends up with the result of `(x1*y2) - (y1*x2)`.

For the cross product you need to treat each component result seperately. That is why the API has the output `result` variables. Store the result into those variables:

```
*result_x = (y1 * z2) - (z1 * y2);
*result_y = (z1 * x2) - (x1 * z2);
*result_z = (x1 * y2) - (y1 * x2);
```